# Inline Raw SVG has worse quality than when placed in <img> tag

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am creating SVGs directly in the client. Therefore, in my Javascript in the client I am creating the raw SVG and manipulating it depending on the user input.
I took the raw SVG and placed it in a file and then displayed that SVG file right next to the raw inline SVG. The result was much more crispy.
Here is the raw inline SVG:
[image: RAW INLINE SVG]

Compare this to the SVG when placed in a file and using an  tag:
[image: SVG INSIDE IMG TAG]

As you can see the quality varies a lot!

Here is a codepen link so that you can directly grab the raw SVG if you would like to perform tests: https://codepen.io/fabiansvensson/pen/WNMJpQr

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- THE RAW SVG -->
<svg></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Importantly, I did notice that the quality seems to be better in the codepen, which leads me to think that perhaps the problem has something to do with the styling of the page. I haven't been able to find any reason why this might be. I am considering writing the raw SVG directly to file (not ideal) or somehow making the styling of the SVG independent from the rest of the page (e.g. iFrame).

Any ideas what might be causing this and how to solve the problem?

Comment: I just added a copy of your inline SVG to your page (script: `const image = document.body.appendChild( new Image ),svg = document.querySelector( 'svg' ); image.src = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8," + encodeURIComponent(svg.outerHTML)";`, css: `svg, img { width: 500px; height: 500px; object-fit: contain; }`) and I see no difference between rendering on page or as a separate document.

Comment: It's not clear from your question which one you thing is bad.  "Crispy" means bad to some people and good to others. A lot depends on how you specify the `<img>` tag. What size are you making the image?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Sorry mate, I mean high quality by crispy. The other image is slightly blurred as you can see by looking at the avatars and the text.

Comment: So far, I can see the difference in the screeenshots (if I look at them at original size, not scaled down as when embeded right here), but I cannot reproduce the blurring effect. Since you seem to have the same problem when transfering your content to CodePen, there must be a difference between the page setup there and the original one that producedf the blurring. So far, we you did not give any information on what that may be.

Comment: Its not all SVG, why don't you use the WEBP image inside the SVG